# ASM-creating a procedure

Tags: assembly, x86

An Array A and Array B were set.
The procedure will get an value V and return if the value exist in array B or not.
If it does-store the index in P, if not, store -1 in P.
The program should begin with the following datas:

```
ARR_B DB 100 DUP()
ARR_A DB 10 DUP ()
V DB ?
P DB ?
```

Here's what we did:

```
TEST1 PROC
; Chek if the variable of V  found in ARR_B.
MOV SI,0
MOV DX,0
MOV Flag,0
MOV AL,1H
NEG AL
MOV CX,9H
GO:
    MOV DL,ARR_B[SI]
    CMP  V,DL
    JE X
    INC SI
    LOOP GO
    MOV  P,AL
    JMP END1
X:  MOV DX,SI
    MOV  P,DL
        INC FLAG
END1:   NOP
    RET
TEST1 endp
```

(flag in used on the following option)

Comment: Please could you format your question so that it's readable.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd normally want to do a search like this using `rep scasb`:

```
test1 proc
    mov P, 0ffffh ; for now, assume it won't be found
    mov al, V                ; what we're going to look for
    mov di, offset array_b   ; where we're going to look
    mov cx, size array_b     ; how many items to search
    repnz scasb              ; do the search
    jnz done                 ; Z flag clear = not found
    sub di, offset array_b   ; found: compute offset into array_b
    mov P, di                ;        and save it
done:
    ret
```